# Android app cant read sharedPreference file in some phones

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Am building an app for a client and everything seems to be working just fine except for one thing. I am writing stuffs like username and password to a sharedPreference file. when i run the app in devices that use android versions like jellybean,kitkat and even lollipop it works like charm but when i try running it on samsung s5, asus zenfone 5.0 it does not read any username or password. Please any form of assistance will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

code for saving my data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("UserId",userId);
editor.putString("Username",getUsername);
editor.putString("Password",getPassword);
editor.putString("Firstname",getFirstname);
editor.putString("Lastname", getLastname);
boolean edited = editor.commit();
```

code for reading the data

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
username = sharedPref.getString("Username", "username");
firstname = sharedPref.getString("Firstname", "firstname");
lastname = sharedPref.getString("Lastname", "lastname");`
```

Answer (score 0):

change the path of SharePreference ,try again

```
try {
        Field field =ContextWrapper.class.getDeclaredField("mBase");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object obj = field.get(this);
        field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPreferencesDir");
        field.setAccessible(true);       
        File file = new File("YOUR PATH");
        field.set(obj, file);

        // use edit to save data
        //…………

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```